# How to add oracle jdbc driver dependency to JIRA plugin?

Tags: java, oracle, jira, jira-plugin

I tried this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>${ojdbc6.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

but with no success.
I failed because of absence of ora18n, I added it also, but it failed with another oracle dependency, etc.

How to add it?

Comment: The Oracle's drivers are not available in Maven Central Repository. You must either follow [this instruction](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides) to connect to Oracle's maven repository, or download driver's JAR and install in manually into your local maven repository, or use some Maven repository manager like JFrog or Nexust and install this jar there.

Comment: thx! installed, but JIRA wants also orai18n, after addition of all required libs, it fails with OSGI error. So it is better to find working example.

Answer (score 1):

> but JIRA wants also orai18n, after addition of all required libs, it fails with OSGI error

Try to use "optional" resolution for dependency.
In your pom.xml find Import-Package in your maven-jira-plugin. 
Then add string like that:

```
some.package.with.dependency.what.was.not.found.*;resolution:="optional",
```

May be it helps